# Custom Post Type Field Array parsing

Tags: custom-post-types, array, parse

I have a CPT Field named 'course_location' as a checkbox with values. When I use

```
 $field = get_field_object('course_location');
'<pre>searchDateArray'; print_r($field); echo '</pre>';
```

Which results in the following array

```
Array (
[key] => field_56056d11c5dd6
[label] => Course Location
[name] => course_location
[_name] => course_location
[type] => checkbox
[order_no] => 3
[instructions] =>
[required] => 0
[id] => acf-field-course_location
[class] => checkbox
[conditional_logic] => Array (
    [status] => 0
    [rules] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [field] => null
            [operator] => ==
            )
    )
    [allorany] => all
)
[choices] => Array (
    [orange-county] => Orange County
    [los-angeles-county] => Los Angeles County
    [test] => Test
)
[default_value] =>
[layout] => vertical
[field_group] => 29
[value] => Array (
    [0] => test
)
```

)

How do I get get the [choices] Array and iterate through the 'choices' and echo out?

`<li>$label and $name</li>`

Output : orange-county and Orange County

Output : los-angeles-county and Los Angeles County

Output : test and Test

Comment: Did you find a solution to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the choices array inside `$field` variable:

```
$choices = $field[ 'choices' ];
```

From there, you can iterate with either a while or foreach loop depending on what you are trying to do with the array.

EDIT: rereading your question, you specify what you are trying to do!  Sorry for skipping that part!

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($choices as $key => $choice):
  echo '<li>' . $key . ' and ' . $choice . '</li>';
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
```

Should produce:

- orange_county and Orange County
- los-angeles and Los Angeles

This should not be considered complete code.  Escape your output for security's sake.  Just illustrating a concept here.